# how to make this code drier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, haml

I am wondering if it is possible to make this code even simpler. I am worried t be hitting the database too many times with the same query. Here is my code:

```
#hot-panel.mdl-tabs__panel.is-active
 %ul.product-list-three.mdl-list
  - @merchant.products.where('products.prototype_id = 1').select(&:id).flatten.uniq.each do |item|
   = render :partial => 'product', :locals => {:item => item }
#cold-panel.mdl-tabs__panel
 %ul.product-list-three.mdl-list
  - @merchant.products.where('products.prototype_id = 2').select(&:id).flatten.uniq.each do |item|
   = render :partial => 'product', :locals => {:item => item }
```

Here are the logs:

```
Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "variants" ON "products"."id" = "variants"."product_id" INNER JOIN "variant_merchants" ON "variants"."id" = "variant_merchants"."variant_id" WHERE "variant_merchants"."merchant_id" = $1 AND (products.prototype_id = 1)  [["merchant_id", 1]]
default_url_options is passed options: {}

  Rendered shopping/merchants/_product.html.haml (3.5ms)
  Product Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "variants" ON "products"."id" = "variants"."product_id" INNER JOIN "variant_merchants" ON "variants"."id" = "variant_merchants"."variant_id" WHERE "variant_merchants"."merchant_id" = $1 AND (products.prototype_id = 2)  [["merchant_id", 1]]
  Rendered shopping/merchants/_product.html.haml (0.5ms)
```

Models
Merchant

```
 has_many :variant_merchants
 has_many :variants, through: :variant_merchants, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products, through: :variants, dependent: :destroy
```

Product

```
 belongs_to :prototype
 has_many :product_properties
 has_many :properties, through: :product_properties

 has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
```

Variant

```
 has_many :variant_merchants, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :merchants, through: :variant_merchants

 has_many :variant_properties
 has_many :properties, through: :variant_properties
```

Product Partial

```
= link_to shopping_merchant_product_path(@merchant, item.id) do
  %li.mdl-list__item.mdl-list__item--three-line
    %span.mdl-list__item-primary-content
      %span= item.name
      %span.mdl-list__item-text-body
        = item.description
    %span.mdl-list__item-secondary-content
      %i.material-icons
        chevron_right
```

Comment: show us your product partial and `merchant`, `product`, and `variant` relationships would help

Comment: can we see your `_product` partial? not sure what the item is that's being passed into it, is item the `products.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can make a variable like

```
@merchant_product_lists = @merchant.products.where("products.prototype_id" => [1, 2]).group_by(&:prototype_id)
```

And then in your view

```
#hot-panel.mdl-tabs__panel.is-active
 %ul.product-list-three.mdl-list
  = render partial: 'product', collection: @merchant_product_lists[1]
#cold-panel.mdl-tabs__panel
 %ul.product-list-three.mdl-list
  = render partial: 'product', collection: @merchant_product_lists[2]
```

`@merchant.products.where("products.prototype_id" => [1, 2]).group_by(&:prototype_id)` will only call the database once, and use ruby method `group_by` to group the result by `products.prototype_id` which will give you a hash mapping `prototype_id to products`, when you display them in the view, you only need to call the corresponding `prototype_id` to retrieve the products